# What is the use of stringbuilder.appendformat(); in asp.net c#?

Tags: stringbuilder

```
foreach (string item in sc)
{
    const string sqlStatement = "Delete From tablename Where field";
    stringbuilder.AppendFormat("{0}='{1}'; ", sqlStatemnt, item);
}
```

I want to know tht what `stringbuilder.appendformat()` exactly does?

Comment: 1 - why not try it 2 - why not read the documentation?

Comment: Also, never build SQL statements like this. You'll leave yourself open to sql injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it instead of the following:

```
sb.append(String.Format("{0} = {1}", a, b));
```

its very recommended to use Format methods because its keeps the code clean and very readable .

it can reduce the reading drastically and also help to format different types, for example (taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx)

```
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 7, 1);
  TimeSpan hiTime = new TimeSpan(14, 17, 32);
  decimal hiTemp = 62.1m; 
  TimeSpan loTime = new TimeSpan(3, 16, 10);
  decimal loTemp = 54.8m; 

  string result1 = String.Format("Temperature on {0:d}:\n{1,11}: {2} degrees (hi)\n{3,11}: {4} degrees (lo)", date1, hiTime, hiTemp, loTime, loTemp);
```